# How do you find the subset of $2\times3$ matrices that forms a basis for a subspace $V$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

[image]

I know know how to find a seubet of vectors that forms a basis but how can you from a basis with matrices?

Comment: Matrices are vectors, just written differently. :)

Answer (score 1):

This vector space, $V$, (a subspace of $M_{23}$), has elements that are matrices.  A basis therefore consists of a set of matrices that are linearly independent and spanning.  It could be $\{A_1, A_2, A_3, A_4\}$, or it could be some subset of those four.

To calculate which subset exactly, you can write the six elements of each matrix as columns into a larger matrix, which will be $6\times 4$, then put that matrix in row echelon form using elementary row operations.  The columns with the pivots will then tell you which of the matrices to include in that basis.